# Defining Query Parameters in SOAPUI as variable

Tags: soapui

I am new to SOAPUI and hopefully, this has a very simple answer that I can't find using the search here and on Google. I have a Rest request that takes query parameters and I would like to supply query parameter value through a script. I have defined a property in project called "nameString" and used "{#Project#nameString} as the value of query parameter. However, when I execute the query, it doesn't replace the parameter value with the nameString value defined in properties.

Following is the setup on query:
[image: Query Parameter Value]

The project property setup looks as follows:
[image: project property]

How do I correct this query parameter value?

Thanks

Comment: Use this `${#Project#nameString}`, No `'` and `#` after the key

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and it doesn't seem to replace the values.

Comment: I have updated my comment, check and let me know

Comment: Yes, initially, I tried without ' or # but it didn't work, after that I was trying other syntax. However, {#Project#nameString} doesn't get translated

Answer (score 0):

Property expansion is covered in the [official documentation](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion/).

In your case, the value should be `${#Project#nameString}`, no additional quotes and no trailing pound sign.